# Is there a logical relationship between constructions of the reals and proof methods in real analysis?

Tags: lo.logic, real-analysis, proof-theory

In my elementary real analysis course three years ago, I remember noting that there seemed to be 3 main ways of proving the main theorems about continuity. There was Bolzano-Weierstrass, continuous induction, and the bisection argument.
At the time, I explained this to myself by thinking these must correspond to the three common constructions of the reals, i.e., Cauchy sequence construction, Dedekind cut construction and (binary) decimal construction, respectively. And that they're natural ways to reason within the corresponding construction.

I was wondering if there's some sort of logical connection here, between the construction of the reals and the methods you can use for proving properties of it? I was wondering if there are other proofs corresponding to more exotic constructions such as Eudoxus reals? Is this an example of something more general?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth noting that in constructive mathematics without assuming any form of Choice, we have three possibly very distinct sets of reals: the Dedekind reals, the Cauchy reals (actually two there, depending on whether we demand a modulus of convergence), and the reals having a binary expansion. Only the first behave nicely: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00639 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00648

Comment: Yes, this was one reason I'm interested in the answer to this.

Comment: What is continuous induction?

Comment: @LSpice If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ with the property that if $V$ is a subset of $U$ then so is the closure of $V$, and $U$ contains some element, then $U = \mathbb R$. I think that's what he meant.

Comment: More succinctly, the only two subsets of $\mathbb R$ which are simultaneously closed and open are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$. The role of $\mathbb R$ can be switched for any connected space.

Comment: E.g. The proof of IVT where you show true for [0,a) then must be true for [0,a] and that if true at a then must be true at some a+$\varepsilon$ and so conclude that it is true for [0,1]. This is also sometimes presented by asking what the supremum of the set of elements d such that the theorem holds for [0,d] is, and concluding that it must be 1.

Comment: This is a trivial observation, but if you define a set $S$ by $S = \{x : \phi(x)\}$ then to prove that $x \in S$, you simply have to show $\phi(x)$. Since the Dedekind and Cauchy reals are defined by different predicates $\phi$, the answer to your question should be yes, but for purely tautological reasons.

Comment: @LSpice See also [these notes of Pete Clark](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0973).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415194/is-there-a-logical-relationship-between-constructions-of-the-reals-and-proof-met#comment1064950_415194)!

Comment: To the OP, one thing to look at might be (reasonably-naturally-occurring) toposes in which the different constructions **don't** wind up being equivalent in the relevant sense, in the hope that the different versions of the reals would actually have meaningfully different properties. I'm sure a lot is known about this ... unfortunately, none of it by *me*.

Comment: yeah I think Noah is right,  you would need to go to a setting where these approaches are not equivalent, maybe some kind of intuitionistic setting.

Comment: About Eudoxus reals: this the construction that most easily establishes that $\mathbb R$ is the maximal Archimedean ordered field.

Comment: Perhaps the link you are looking for can be gleaned from the following article:    Hirst, Jeffry L, Representations of reals in reverse mathematics, Bull. Pol. Acad. Sci. Math., 2007.  Hirst discusses various representations of the real numbers.  I would not be surprised if (Bolzano-Weierstrass/Heine-Borel/...) and the attendant RM systems line up with the systems needed to convert between the representations under discussion.